# TouchID activateTouchWithResponse returns success without requesting fingerprint

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

I have the following implementation of LocalAuthentication as described in many places.

```
context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Logging in with Touch ID", reply: { (success : Bool, error : NSError? ) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        if success {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "", cancelButtonTitle: "Great!")
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        if let error = error {
            var message :String

            switch(error.code) {
            case LAError..AuthenticationFailed:
                message = "There was a problem verifying your identity."
            case LAError..UserCancel:
                message = "You pressed cancel."
            case LAError..UserFallback:
                message = "You pressed password."
            default:
                message = "Touch ID may not be configured"
            }

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, cancelButtonTitle: "Darn!")
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
})
```

But after I've successfully authenticated with my fingerprint, then evaluatePolicy(, localizedReason:, reply:) returns success without requesting for any fingerprint.
I'm actually enabling or disabling TouchID with a UISwitch, so after disabling and re enabling, I'd like to re-authenticate and re enter my fingerprint.

Why is it caching the authentication?

Thanks

Comment: add the error as an else if and see what happens.

Comment: Error is nil. The second time I evaluate the policy I get success and error nil without being prompt to touch the button.

Comment: Try doing if error != nil instead

Answer (score 35, accepted):

LAContext, once evaluated, will return success until it's deallocated. You can manually invalidate it and then the returned error will be LAError.InvalidContext.

If you want to be prompted with a TouchID confirmation every time, you need to create a LAContext every time. This could be achieved

```
context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Logging in with Touch ID", reply: { (success : Bool, error : NSError? ) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        if success {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "", cancelButtonTitle: "Great!")
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        if let error = error {
            var message :String

            switch(error.code) {
            case LAError..AuthenticationFailed:
                message = "There was a problem verifying your identity."
            case LAError..UserCancel:
                message = "You pressed cancel."
            case LAError..UserFallback:
                message = "You pressed password."
            default:
                message = "Touch ID may not be configured"
            }

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, cancelButtonTitle: "Darn!")
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        context = LAContext()
    })
})
```

Comment: Great answer, it cleared situation, thanks.
There is no any word about it in Apple docs, and phrase:

"Don’t assume that a previous successful policy evaluation means that future evaluations will also succeed. Policy evaluation can fail for various reasons, including cancellation by the user or the system."

really confusing.

Comment: Using `touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration` is the intended (and better) solution to this problem.

Answer (score 9):

Since ios 9 there is `touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration` for the context

> The duration for which Touch ID authentication reuse is allowable.
>   If the device was successfully authenticated using Touch ID within the specified time interval, then authentication for the receiver succeeds automatically, without prompting the user for Touch ID.
>   The default value is 0, meaning that Touch ID authentication cannot be reused.
>   The maximum allowable duration for Touch ID authentication reuse is specified by the LATouchIDAuthenticationMaximumAllowableReuseDuration constant. You cannot specify a longer duration by setting this property to a value greater than this constant.
>   Availability    iOS (9.0 and later), macOS (10.12 and later)

if you set for example to 60

```
context.touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration = 60
```

It will auto succeed without checking, if the user has successfully passed the touch id checking in the last 60 secs.

So, you can set to the value that suites you. I find it a good very good and it's annoying to ask the user to touch again while he just did it a few seconds ago.(to unlock the screen for example).

Comment: Note that as of iOS 13.2 SDK the documentation reads "If the device was successfully _**unlocked**_ by biometry within this time interval, (...)".

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem but then I increased the duration value as below:

```
context.touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration = Double(5 * 60) // 5 min,
```

This solution worked for me.

Comment: You could have used the constant LATouchIDAuthenticationMaximumAllowableReuseDuration because it is the maximum Allowed time interval. Its value is 5 min only.